# How to control the memory usage of a swap partiotion?

Tags: swap

Thats pretty much the quesiton: how can I control the memory usage of each swap partiotion, say /etc/sa5?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it, memory usage of swap partition? It depends on the anonymous memory which is moved to swap during memory reclaim.

You can set priority on the swap partition however. Also, did you mention /etc/sa5 correctly. If I am not wrong, I haven't seen any such file.

Comment: If your swap file is in /etc you need to update the unix version you are using ;)

Comment: Exactly my thought.